# Declare a variable and initialize it from a file, all at once

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
ifstream f("data.txt");
string dat;
f >> dat;
```

Is there any way to combine this into one statement, so I could declare and initialize the variable all in one go?

I tried

```
string dat << f;
```

But it gave me a syntax error.

Comment: No, but depending what `f` is and has, there could be another way.

Comment: How about declaring a function?

Comment: @catscradle That might be a good idea, like `readLine(f)`. If you post that as an answer I'll upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The longer answer is, "you can do something that does this, but far from as directly".

```
 template <typename T>
 T read_from_file(const char *fname)
 {
     T v;
     ifstream f("data.txt");
     f >> v;
     return v;
 }


 ... 

 string dat = read_from_file("data.txt");
```

However, this doesn't work particularly well if you have anything more than a single data entry [of course, if there is a structure or class with an `operator<<` declared for the class, it can be used for a structure, but you can't use it, say, to read an array of 10 structs containing the top ten high scores of a game].

And whilst the above is a "clever" little piece of code, the more "natural" code of reading the data after opening the file in a few lines of code will be much clearer.